# Python running ffmpeg with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, ffmpeg, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run `ffmpeg` command with `multiprocessing` in parallel tasks.
My python `ffmpeg` call to be parallelized is the following:

```
def load_audio(args, kwargs):
    url = args

    start = kwargs["start"]
    end = kwargs["end"]
    sr = kwargs["sr"]
    n_channels = kwargs["n_channels"]
    mono = kwargs["mono"]

    cmd = ["ffmpeg",  "-i", url, "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", "-ac", str(n_channels), "-ar", str(sr), "-ss", _to_ffmpeg_time(start), "-t", _to_ffmpeg_time(end - start), "-sn", "-vn", "-y", "-f", "wav", "pipe:1"]

    process = subprocess.run(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8
    )
    buffer = process.stdout
    waveform = np.frombuffer(buffer=process.stdout, dtype=np.uint16, offset=8 * 44)
    waveform = waveform.astype(dtype)
    return waveform
```

I then read the audio by offset `60 seconds`:

```
_THREAD_POOL = BoundedThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NTHREADS)
tasks = []
cur_start = start
for i in range(NTHREADS):
    msg = {'start':cur_start,
           'end':min(cur_start+60,end)}
    t = execute_callback(load_audio, 
                         'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3', 
                         msg)
    cur_start+=60
    tasks.append(t)
```

where `execute_callback` will submit the thread to the pool:

```
def execute_callback(fn, args, kwargs):
    try:
        futures_thread = _THREAD_POOL.submit(fn, args, kwargs)
        return futures_thread
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```

I finally retrieve the results, and concat to a `numpy` array (that will go to `soundfile` to be read)

```
futures_results = get_results_as_completed(tasks, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
waveform = []
for i,r in enumerate(futures_results):
    if not i:
        waveform = r
        print(type(r))
    else:
        waveform = np.append(waveform,r)
```

where `get_results_as_completed` is

```
def get_results_as_completed(futures, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED):
        finished = as_completed(futures)
        for f in finished:
            try:
                yield f.result()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

where I'm using the bounded pool executor class [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/c4de40a84f59ed77c6cb98cd0c499659) and [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/d091574f8eac92977b97b9f3eae32679).
I'm using `as_completed` to retrieve the futures in completed states, that causes the output to not be preserved in the input order, but the "completion" order, this cause the audio output to be wrong. My questions are

- Are the `ffmpeg` futures actually executed in parallel? In my tests downloading the whole audio like:

  ```
       args = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3'
       kwargs = {'start':start, 
            'end':end}
       waveform = load_audio(args,kwargs)
  ```
- Is it possibile to preserve the input order for the results **without** using semaphores, but only `multiprocessing` functions (`map` may be?). If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you are using `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor` you are technically multithreading and each thread is then running a process (more on this later).

Regardless, your function `execute_callback`, whose name is a bit confusing to me, actually submits a task to the pool and returns a `Future` instance which then gets appended to list `tasks`. You then pass `tasks` to `get_results_as_completed`, which yields the return values from your tasks in order of completion. But this is not what you want.

So to answer your second question first: If you don't want the results in completion order, just don't use function `as_completed`. Instead call:

```py
def get_results(futures):
    for f in futures:
        try:
            yield f.result()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

To answer your first question: multithreading is generally not what you want for CPU-intensive Python code since there is contention for the Global Interpreter Lock. But since each thread is launching a process and waiting for the process to end, I would think you should achieve parallelization and I see no reason why the input order should not be maintained because of my previous answer.

Now for my question and comment:

1. Why `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor` instead of just using the standard `ThreadPoolExecutor`?
2. In function definitions where you have argument signatures with `args` and `kwargs` as arguments, e.g. `load_audio`, it would be more "normal" to specify these arguments as `*args` and `**kwargs` and you would then call this function thus: `load_audio('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3', start=start, end=end)`.

Comment: Thank you. I’m using the bounded thread pool executor to have more control over the number of threads spawned. This because that code was initially running within Tornado server and it was (my understanding) a safer way to avoid threads pressure; 2) correct thanks reason was I was using “ffmpeg-python” wrapper, that had kwargs…; I will try the “get_results” then.

Comment: If you adopt the standard `*args, **kwargs` convention, then in `load_audio` you will have `url = args[0]`.

Comment: The `get_results` works as expected, thanks. The last "opened" point is why calling `load_audio` on the whole file is faster than calling `load_audio` in chunks of 60 seconds of audio...

Comment: I have asked the last point a s a separate question, cleaning up the code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679832/ffmpeg-download-mp3-in-chunks-slower-than-whole-file

Comment: I looked at your new question. Neither that one nor this one are truly [minimal, reproducible, examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that are runnable as is. For example, in this question `end` and `NTHREADS` are not defined and in your new question `NTHREADS` and `process_list` are not defined.  (more ...)

Comment: When I run `ffmpeg -i https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ss 0:08:55.780000 -t 0:01:00.000000 -sn -vn -y -f wav pipe:1 >test.mpeg` I get: *Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)*

Comment: this is because you cannot run by shell if you use “pipe:1”; you have to remove this and set a output file or device; with pipe you go to stdout;

Comment: thanks I will do the corrections to make it reproducible

Comment: I ran the above at a DOS prompt. With different values of -ss and -t, for example *-ss 0:00:0.000000 -t 0:00:44.000000* it works.

Comment: Also, I believe according to the documentation, when you specify a starting time offset, ffmpeg cannot be exact about it so what you are ultimately assembling will not be strictly perfect.

Comment: BTW decorator functions `threadpool` and `processpool`  defined [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/d091574f8eac92977b97b9f3eae32679) are written incorrectly. I can't see value in a `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor`. If you create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance with a pool size of 5, you will never have more than 5 concurrent threads running even if the queue has tasks waiting to run.  A `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor` guarantees there will never be a queue of tasks waiting to run by blocking the main thread from submitting a task until there is a free thread. Why is that desirable?

Comment: thanks for you analysis it was a code specific to run threads within tornado web server, to avoid tornado api calls to that api (that uses concurrent code) to spread more than N threads. At least this was as it was intended to.