# ffmpeg download mp3 in chunks slower than whole file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, multiprocessing, mp3

I'm programmatically downloading in Python mp3 file's as `wav` chunks, seeking at position with `ss` and `t` with `ffmpeg` resulting in a sequence of `ffmpeg` commands

```
ffmpeg -i https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ss 0:08:55.780000 -t 0:01:00.000000 -sn -vn -y -f wav pipe:1
ffmpeg -i https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ss -ss 0:09:55.780000 -t 0:01:00.000000 -sn -vn -y -f wav pipe:1
ffmpeg -i https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ss -ss -ss 0:10:55.780000 -t 0:01:00.000000 -sn -vn -y -f wav pipe:1
...
```

executed via `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` in this way:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NTHREADS) as executor:
        for i,cmd in enumerate(process_list):
            futures.append(executor.submit(downloader.chunk_download,(cmd,i)))

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                completed.append(future.result())
            except Exception as e:print(e)
    completed.sort() 
    for k,c in enumerate(completed):
        if not k:
            waveform = c[1]
        else:
            waveform = np.append(waveform,c[1])
```

where `chunk_download` is concat the chunks into the whole waveform

```
def chunk_download(self,args):
        cmd=args[0]
        i=args[1]
        print('Downloading chunk n° %i' % i)

        print( ' '.join(cmd))
        process = subprocess.run(cmd,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            bufsize=10**8)
        #buffer, stderr = process.communicate()
        buffer = process.stdout
        stderr = process.stderr
        print('chunk n° %i DOWNLOADED' % i)
        # convert to signal
        chunk_waveform = np.frombuffer(buffer=buffer, dtype=np.uint16, offset=8*44)
        chunk_waveform = chunk_waveform.astype(self.dtype)  
        print(len(chunk_waveform)/44100) 

        return i,chunk_waveform
```

this works ok, but if I download the whole mp3, executing the command in `cmd` like:

```
ffmpeg -i https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -sn -vn -y -f wav pipe:1
```

It will take less time than the concurrent chunks download for the same file length, while I would expect the opposite. Could be this related to `ffmpeg` threading option (param `--thread`?). If not, why the concurrent chunks download operation is slower?

Comment: Running the command in `cmd` is calling compiled C a single time. You do the same when running it multi-threaded with chunks but you have the overhead of calling the subprocesses and most importantly saving the results in Python. Can you time the part of your script where you process the buffer after your subprocess call until the end of your script and compare it to the whole runtime?

Comment: @hlzl thanks, adding the timing computed on the output aggregation and before.

Comment: Any updates on the time measurements?